# Remove 'Validate call on component 'Flat file disassembler' failed' warning

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-pipelines

I am getting a warning

> warning BTP0008: Validate call on component 'Flat file disassembler' failed.

Is there any way to remove this warning? I dont have any problem while running though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning on building biztalk application: 'Validate call on on component 'Flat File Disassembler' failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23316604/warning-on-building-biztalk-application-validate-call-on-on-component-flat-fi)

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link similar question.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1166dfd-8f4f-4347-aabe-87ac17ce8600/validate-call-on-component-flat-file-disassembler-failed?forum=biztalkgeneral